# Old activity not picking up on a theme I created, but new activities do. How do I get the old one to use my theme?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm new to all of this so please bear with me.

A while back I created my first activity and have been working on it for a while now.  Since then, I've created a theme and applied it to my application.  The theme doesn't show up on my original activity.. it still looks default:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/rkSyhmg.png]

I just now created a new activity, and it seems to have picked up on my theme design and looks totally different.  The font size is different in the action bar, and all the colors are different.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/7IpnGev.png]

Why is this happening?  The theme works on both when I actually run the app in the emulator.. but they look different in eclipse.  How can I get my old activity to pick up on the theme?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option on the layout design which you can choose which theme you want to be used on preview.

Comment: What a simple fix, thank you.. I was searching all over in the code to see if I had missed something.

Comment: Sometimes it is cool for multiple themes tests... don't forget to accept my answer pleas =]